# Attempting to add a Dash movement option using Unity and C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a very simple platformer game, not to publish or anything like that but rather to experiment with Unity and C#, and I've been trying to make a dash mechanic. two ways that I tried to go about this were

1. Getting the players position and teleporting them in any one direction, depending on the direction of the dash, didn't work because I couldn't figure out how to find the player's position
2. Making the player move fast in any one direction, didn't work because of how the rest of the movement script works.

I would prefer to use the first option, does anyone know how to find the players location? I think I was able to find the transform position, but I didn't know how to use it since it was 3 values, x, y, and z, rather than one, and I didn't know how to only get 1. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add code. And why can't you find your players position. Is the movement controller no on the player?

Comment: @MrMoonMan, i think he is a beginner and don't know about `Vector3` or the API, also, sorry if the API has changed and am talking about outdated code, it's been a while since I code in Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a definitive answer, since this depends on the code you are using and i have **not** shown how to dash, there is a lot of camera code and i am not coding unity anymore, so guessing this out without tests seem wrong, i would recommend adding the code, but the first option is simple enough to an answer.

In the player script, use `transform.position`, this will not fail since all Unity GameObjects have a world position, and therefore a transform.

```cs
// not sure if i spelled correctly
public class Player: Monobehaviour {
    /* ... */

    void Dash () {
        // transform.position is the current position as a 3D vector
       var pos = transform.position;

       // to access its x, y and z do this:
       var x = pos.x;
       var y = pos.y;
       var z = pos.z;
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on the dash system, you would need to detect the camera position, raycast, or simply enough, catch the press of buttons.

Comment: I think that should be enough for me, what I really meant to ask was "when I get the player's position, how do I separate it into x, y, and z?" which you answered, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! I sugest looking into the Unity srcipting API (Aplication Programming Interface), it tell all about the tools you use to code in Unity, like `Vector3` which is the type of the `transform.position`, if that is enough for you, I would also be glad if marked this post as solved.

Comment: Thank you, ill make sure to look into that!

Comment: Also, in the last comment i accidently mispelled "scripting"